# Thingsboard.cloud MQTT Bridge - hex sting payload

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I am working with a dragino NB IoT device pushing a string representation of a hex value as a payload via MQTT basic authentication. I am trying to get this into azure IoT eventually but the dragino doesn't support TLS as required by azure. I am therefore attempting to bridge using thingsboard cloud.

At this point I am just trying to get TB to receive the data and have set up a device with MQTT basic authentication which tests OK using MQTT Box and a json 'attribute' payload as long as I have a client ID.

[image]

I have also set up a uplink data converter to process the hex string to attributes.

[image]

I am assuming the integration links the device to the uplink converter such that when I push the payload to TB the data converter picks it up transforms it as required and puts in in the attributes of the device.

[image]

I was guessing (?!?!) the integration uses the device's username and password for MQTT basic auth to intercept the incoming payload and push it to the device attributes but I clearly have something wrong here.

I am aiming to push this out to MQTT azure or possibly a webhook but I simply cant get step one to work at the moment.

TB support has provided links to uplink and integration but reading all the documentation I can't work out how to pull this all together.

Desperately seeking advice!!